# show preview of pdf file saved in gridfs on browser

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb, symfony, gridfs

I'm using `gridfs` to store files in MongoDB. I'm facing a problem when I try to show the large pdf file in the browser, which is saved in `gridfs`. Large files don't show up in the browser, but small files does.

This is the service code

```
public function getIpFileByFileId() {
    $request = $this->request;
    $dm = $this->container->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager('patient');
    $id = $request->get('fileId');
    //get doc
    $docIpMapping = $dm->getRepository('PatientDocumentsBundle:IPDocuments')->findOneBy([
        'id' => $id
    ]);
    $base64 = (base64_encode($docIpMapping->getFile()->getBytes()));
    $response['data'] = $base64;
    $response['msg'] = 'success';
    return $response;
}
```

And this is the front end code

```
Ajax(path, data).success(function (result) {
                        $("#pdfDiv").html('<iframe style="width:100%;height:500px;" src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + result.data + '"></iframe>');
                });
```

Does the code have any issues? How do I display large files in the front end?

Comment: why not make a url directly in your url via your action, it might be easier example: myurl.com/pdf/my-super-pdf.pdf ?

Comment: @Flug if I show the file as .pdf url then I need to save the file in server as pdf, is there any option to show as .pdf url without saving file in server?

Comment: well you can make a pdf view with your answer and with the pdf content type. You can do it dynamically without storing it on your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, without open in new tab,
http://answerexpress.blogspot.com/2018/09/show-preview-of-pdf-file-saved-in.html

Comment: Only link answers are pretty discouraged (they could change or die during time) so please, report it inside your answer (easy and fast).